# Embed Git Commit Log in Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control, logging, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I have a 'development blog' in a rails app I'm working on right now. I'm using Git for version control and deployment (although right now I'm the only person working on it).

Now, when I make changes in Git I put a pretty decent log entry about what I've done. I'd love to have the Git commit log automatically posted to the development blog -- or otherwise available for others to read within the deployed site.

Is there an automated way to pull the Git Commit Log into a view in a rails app?

Comment: Just a quick thank you to the answerers so far, these suggestions have been very helpful and I appreciate that they're each offering a unique but viable approach!

Comment: Still doing some tests, each option is interesting. I'll pick an answer when I figure out which way works best for me, but I'm still interested if anyone else has other ideas about how to do this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some Git hosts will allow you to provide a post commit hook, and this can enable you to make an HTTP call to send the relevant log statements to your app.

If you're self-hosting, check out [githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

If you're using Github, you can use their post-commit post (more details here: http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/)

Comment: In fact, Github will simply show the commit log for you under "Commits".

Comment: Ok, so I've never heard of git hooks before, but that's very helpful. I'm self-hosting, so... if I put an executable file called post-commit then in theory that could post the commit to the site. Can you point me to any resources about how to write a git hook -- preferably in Ruby? Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used this, but it might be helpful: https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git

This link also has some good information: http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html

Comment: I ended up choosing this answer because it was the easiest to implement and it's what I'm using for now. Thanks for everyone who answered the question!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into [grit](http://grit.rubyforge.org/) which is a ruby library that gives access to stuff in a git repo.

I'm using grit in my personal blog. I write articles in text files and commit them to a git repo, then push the git repo to my server where my rails app reads files from git repo as blog posts using grit.

For example, here's how easy it is to get the last commit message:

```
require 'grit'
include Grit
repo = Repo.new('<path to your .git dir>')
puts repo.commits('master',1)[0].message # latest commit message
puts repo.commits('master',1)[0].date # last commit date
```

Comment: Great tip, this may be very useful! I'll check it out.

Comment: So... 'path to your git directory'...  I'm deploying on Heroku and my git directory is local. I don't think that the repo lives on the Heroku servers, at least not in any way that I can reach it (they take it and turn it into what they call a "slug"). But, I do have another private server I could store a copy of the repo on. Will this successfully load a repo from a URL rather than a path?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure about whether <path to your .git dir> can be a url...I'm guessing that it won't work unless the .git directory is local to the rails app. For example, in my case, it's something like: `repo=Repo.new('/home/dparoulek/rails-app/.git')`

Comment: Yeah, after testing this you're right, the repo needs to be local. This works great on my local setup, and would work fine for deployment on something other than heroku :)

Answer (score 1):

I added a Capistrano task to do something similar:

deploy.rb

```
  namespace :deploy do
    desc <<-DESC
      Updates info.html with build and deploy info
    DESC
    task :timestamp do
      run "cd #{current_path}; printf '<pre>\\nDeployed on: %s\\n\\n%s\\n</pre>' \"`date`\" \"`git log -n 1`\" > public/info.html"
    end
  end
  after "deploy", "deploy:timestamp"
```

I just show the last commit, but you could alter the git log command to show whatever you wanted.

Comment: Cool idea! So, in the same vein I could make this a rake task perhaps? I'm deploying with Heroku so no capistrano in my workflow.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do the same thing in a rake task but it looks like Heroku won't let you write out a file like that. It might be better to have the rake task put the git info into a database table and have the info page be a Rails view that pulls from the database.